# Delete all comments in an excel-sheet using xlwings python on MacOS?

Tags: python, excel, macos, xlwings

I am looking for a method to delete all comments in an Excel-sheet using python.

On Windows i can do this using the following command:

```
ws2.used_range.api.ClearComments()
```

But this is not working on Mac.

How can i delete all comments in an excel-sheet using xlwings on Mac?

Comment: So what about a loop for all cells with comments? How to check if cells have comments?

Answer (score 3):

In openpyxl you'd have to do it cell by cell.
In Xlwings you can do cell by cell or range.

For example to clear all cells in a range, either set the range e.g. 'A1:B5' or you can select the range of 'used cells' in the sheet;
(Code works on Windows I do not have MACOS PC)

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

### Clear comments from all cells in range A1:B5
ws.range('A1:B5').api.ClearComments()
### Clear comments from all 'used cells' on the sheet
ws.used_range.api.ClearComments()

...
```

Comment: I like the answer and this works well on Windows - but i need a solution for Mac

Comment: Did you try on MACOS and it didn't work? As you know from Felix that Xlwings with MACOS support is now reduced and unless somebody has already done this you may be on your own. I'd be happy to try by as mentioned I don't have any access to a MACOS PC. The command  `ClearComments()` is basically a duplication of the VBA operation so although it's probably not ideal you can use Xlwings to add and call a VBA macro to do this instead.

Comment: I tried the comment also on Mac.
On Windows it works fine - but i get an error on Mac.